# How to let user select columns to be displayed in table on Qliksense?

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I have a table with a large number of columns so I would like to have a filterpane/listbox with all the dimensions and measures allowing the user to select the columns they would like to see in the table.

My table looks like this where the columns are displayed based on the selection:
[image]

So something like this:

[image]

I tried to do it using [this solution](https://community.qlik.com/t5/QlikView-App-Dev/show-or-hide-column-by-selection/m-p/392808) but it does not appear to do anything. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?/How can I do this?

Here is my script in the load editor where I create the table for the selection:

```
Selection:
load * inline [
Dimension
Category
Revenue
Year
ProductName
ProductID
Date 
];
```

Here is my condition for each of the columns in the table, using column ProductID as an example:
`=SubStringCount(Concat(Measure),1), ProductID)`

Comment: Don't you want `Dimension` in place of measure? You are also missing single quotes around `ProductID`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Set vShowCollumn = Not IsNull(GetFieldSelections($1)) and WildMatch(Concat($2,','),'*$3*');

    I_DIMENSIONS:
    Load
        *
    InLine [
    _Dimension                          ,   _CodDimension
    Product                             ,   001
    Shop                        ,   002
    ];
```

and in the product you choose de number, respondind with your inline, for example:

```
$(vShowcollumn(_Dimension,_CodDimension,001))
```

so, when it gonna show only when user click in the dimension.